# Will I lose friends if I ignore them?

Tags: streetpass, streetpass-mii-plaza

When using the Streetpass feature of Mii Plaza, you walk around and gather 'friends', which shows up as a notification (Green LED light on the 3DS, and a green dot on the game icon).

Can I safely ignore these notifications for an extended period of time, without losing the new friends they bring into the Mii Plaza? (I'm getting sick of watching all my heroes turn back in *Streetpass Quest*, as I'm waiting on someone with White Magic to light up a room). I'm thinking of leaving it from 2 to about 5 days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can safely ignore the gathered StreetPass data for weeks at a time. Keep in mind, however, that while StreetPass Miis will wait patiently at your gate until you check it, that only 10 StreetPass tags can wait in line at a time. Also, if you encounter the same 3DS unit multiple times - Mii Plaza will acknowledge that you've tagged them more than once (and this does not seem to count against the 10), but you still only get one use out of them in each game.

You can check how many Streetpass tags are available for being encountered at your gate through "Notifications" on your home screen (between the friends list and web browser). This should also clear the green notification LED. Once Notifications says you have 10 Streetpass tags for Mii Plaza, you should check them before any others are turned away.

Comment: The note about only 10 StreetPass tags is important. After you max out at 10, no one new will come to the Plaza.