# What unlocks "Hire Old Allies" in Find Mii?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass-quest-find-mii

I can now "Hire Old Allies" for Play Coins in the original version of Find Mii. I thought this was new functionality that appeared with the most recent update, but other people have the update and *can't* hire old allies in Find Mii.

Both my 3DS (Ver 6.2.0-12U) and StreetPass Mii Plaza is updated to the latest version.  I have 148 Play Coins.  I also recently earned the "Completed Find Mii five times" Accomplishment.

What are the conditions to unlock the hiring old heroes in Find Mii?

Comment: Note to answerers, this question follows on from the discussion playing out on this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126868/will-i-lose-friends-if-i-ignore-them

Comment: although, a little spark went off in my head: You've previously completed Find Mii/Streetpass Quest? It's possible that this functionality only becomes available on subsequent playthroughs

Comment: Yes, I had previously completed FM and Find Mii II (both normal and Secret quest) one or two times.  Also, FWIW, I have a NA/US system.

Comment: Yeah I haven't completed it yet, only got my 3DS XL last month (AUS system). It's possible Trent hasn't completed it yet either. I'm thinking that's the reason why, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't completed it either. Sounds like a plausible reason. (I could test it, but for some reason fbueckert's 3DS hasn't tagged mine in weeks, and I'm using play coins on puzzle pieces rather than on expendable minions for the boss of the tower.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just rescued myself from the ultimate ghost again, completing the second run-through of the game. After being awarded the ultimate ghost hat/mask thing, a screen did say that I can now hire old allies using play coins.

So it seems that the condition to unlock this option is indeed beating the ultimate ghost at the end of Find Mii twice.

Comment: I think that this functionality **is** new to the Ver 6.2.0-12U update; I had completed Find Mii four times when I updated, and I saw the new functionality right away.